# Paging in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I'm having some trouble with my asp paging. It's able to show the 6 records on each page. However, when i move on to the second page, it's showing the same 6 records on every different page. 
Below is my code. Any suggestions?

```
 Dim iPageSize,iPageCount , iPageCurrent , strOrderBy,strSQL,iRecordsShown,I  
    iPageSize = 6
    set registerRS=server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    registerRS.PageSize = iPageSize
    ' Retrieve page to show or default to 1
    If Request.QueryString("page") = "" Then
        iPageCurrent = 1
    Else
        iPageCurrent = CInt(Request.QueryString("page"))
    End If
    qry="SELECT * FROM "dbo.CustomerOrders;"

    registerRS.CacheSize = iPageSize
    registerRS.open qry,ObjConn,3
    iPageCount = registerRS.PageCount
    If iPageCurrent > iPageCount Then iPageCurrent = iPageCount
    If iPageCurrent < 1 Then iPageCurrent = 1
    If iPageCount = 0 Then
        Response.Write "No records found!"
    Else
        registerRS.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent
    end if
    %>
        <p>
        <font size="+1">Page <strong><%= iPageCurrent %></strong>
        of <strong><%= iPageCount %></strong></font>
        </p>
    <%
    x=registerRS.recordcount
    if registerRS.recordcount > 0 Then
    registerRS.movefirst
    End If
        Do While iRecordsShown < iPageSize And Not registerRS.EOF
                counter=counter+1
                if counter=41 then
                    counter=0
                    counter=counter+1
                end if
                r = r + 1
                If r = 1 then
                    Response.write "<tr>"
                End if
                %>
                   <td>
                        <%=registerRS.Fields("Address")%> <br />>                
                      </td>          
        <%       
            If r = 2 then
            Response.write "</tr>"
            End if
            If r = 3 then r = 1
            ' Increment the number of records we've shown
                iRecordsShown = iRecordsShown + 1
            registerRS.movenext
            loop            
        %>
</table>  
<table width=90%>
    <tr>
        <td>
<%        
    If iPageCurrent > 1 Then        
%>
    <a href="add.asp?page=<%= iPageCurrent - 1 %>&SchoolId=<%=registerRS.Fields("Add")%>">[&lt;&lt; Prev]</a>
<%
    End If
    ' You can also show page numbers:
        For I = 1 To iPageCount
        If I = iPageCurrent Then
%>
<%= I %>
<%Else%>
    <a href="add.asp?page=<%= I %>&SchoolId=<%=registerRS.Fields("Add")%>"><%= I %></a>     
<%
    End If
    Next 'I
    If iPageCurrent < iPageCount Then
%>
    <a href="add.asp?page=<%= iPageCurrent + 1 %>&SchoolId=<%=registerRS.Fields("Add")%>">[Next &gt;&gt;]</a>
<%
    registerRS.close
    set registerRS=nothing 
    End If
    end sub
%>
```

Comment: honestly, I can't even figure out where in your code you think you're "paging". Paging would imply that there is a parameter in the URL that determines which page to show, and that you show different records based on the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a view source on the web page and verify that this line of code:

```
<a href="add.asp?page=<%= iPageCurrent + 1 %>&SchoolId=<%=registerRS.Fields("Add")%>">[Next &gt;&gt;]</a>
```

is producing the correct result.  If not then you will need to backtrack to find out where the correct page reference is not being generated.

Compare your code to this example for possible error sources.

http://www.asp101.com/samples/viewasp.asp?file=db_paging.asp

I did some testing and I see a couple of things that may be causing problems.

1] You need to initialize iRecordsShown = 0 before the Do-Loop.

2] You are also trying to retrieve database values into you links after the loop.  This won't likely work because the loop has already reached the end of records by that time.  You'll need to capture the database values before the end of loop is reached.

Otherwise it worked for me.

Comment: The html is showing the 7th record it is suppose to display. Any idea on how to make it show in the table?

Comment: your links are pointing to a file called "add.asp" Is that the correct file for listing a table of values ? Is it the name of the file which holds the sample code you have provided ?

Comment: Did you try Kul- Tigin's solution ?

Comment: And the result is still the same. maybe I am not passing the parameter correctly

Comment: I did some testing and I see a couple of other things that may be causing problems.  You need to initialize iRecordsShown = 0 before the Do-Loop.  You are also trying to retrieve database values into you links after the loop.  This won't likely work because the loop has already reached the end of records by that time.  You'll need to capture the database values before the end of loop is reached. Otherwise it worked for me.  I'll add these 2 items to my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following condition block moves cursor to the first record if the number of records greater than zero (should be already). And then loop starts at first record without affecting the page number. This is not sensible, remove that block.

```vb
if registerRS.recordcount > 0 Then
registerRS.movefirst
End If
```